# How to get Line exception

Tags: c#, exception

The question is pretty clear.
And it should work with

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(exc, true);

//Get the first stack frame
StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(0);

//Get the file name
//string fileName = frame.GetFileName();

//Get the line number from the stack frame
int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
```

the problem is that if I launch my application in debug mode it works always.
When I launch it in Release mode it seems it need the pdb files to get this information. So what are the drawbacks of keeping the pdb files (I thought they were needed only in debug mode). Viceversa is this the only way to get the exception line information?

Comment: The compiler re-arranges all your code and removes some lines altogether - release mode optimizes the code heavily and the output "code" may look nothing like your original code. Stack traces don't show line numbers in "release" because that would be impossible to decypher based on the exe (or dll) alone normally.

Comment: But if I keep the pdb files the stack trace does show the line number.

Comment: @Benjamin: You can get line numbers in release mode. However, they may not be 100% accurate because of the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do .pdbs slow down a release application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270986/do-pdbs-slow-down-a-release-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what are the drawbacks of keeping the pdb files (I thought they were needed only in debug mode)

Mostly the fact that it makes for a bigger deployment. Apparently it [doesn't affect performance](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/do-pdb-files-affect-performance).

> Viceversa is this the only way to get the exception line information?

Yes, only the pdb contains the line information. But as mentioned in the comments, the line numbers may not be completely accurate in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the trick you're doing with the pdb files, you need to disable the "Optimize code" options for your project if you need to preserve the lines numbers (Not 100 %). But this is **not recommended** by anyway as it might make your program slower.

You can find that in the build options in the Project properties.

Optimize code rearranges your code removing, moving and adding lines to optimize it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Isn't that trivial from the name "Optimize Code" ?